# how to update few records from table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wanted to update few records from test table to testResult table using where clause as follows,But I am getting all unique values.May i know why i am getting this way.

```
UPDATE       testResult
SET                TRM = te.TRM, timeStamp = te.timeStamp, FWD = te.FWD, OverAll = te.OverAll, ExRFln = te.ExRFln, ExDuty = te.ExDuty, VSWR = te.VSWR, REVPWR = te.REVPWR, 
                         coordinateA = te.coordinateA, coordinateB = te.coordinateB
FROM            test AS te CROSS JOIN
                         testResult
WHERE        (te.timeStamp BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '2013-09-05 18:23:50', 120) AND CONVERT(datetime, '2013-09-05 18:24:59', 120))
```

All the columns have unique data that corresponds to test table where timeStamp is 2013-09-05 18:23:50

This is the test table screenshot showing column values

[image]

this is testResult screenshot showing after execution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want by:

```
select *
into   testResult
from   test
where  timeStamp BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '2013-09-05 18:23:50', 120) AND 
       CONVERT(datetime, '2013-09-05 18:24:59', 120)
```

(this will only work if the testResult table does not already exist)

Comment: I read from your post that you want a `testResults` table with certain rows from the `test` table. If I understood correctly, then you can just create the `testResults` table as I suggested whenever you need it. If you want to insert new rows into the `testResults` table, then you would use `insert into testResults select...`. Updating a row in the `testResults` table with every column from a row in the `test` table makes no sense to me.

Comment: See in Front end I use c# WPF,to create a chart it depends on number of rows.If i have 100 rows then 100 chart will be generated,if 200 then 200 charts will be generated.My number of chart should be constant(in my case 600).So i need only 600 rows.Hence I can not insert new rows.I need only update.Hope you have understood me

Comment: If you only want 600 rows, add `TOP 600` to your query

Comment: @paul I can not write sql commands in c# WPF .xaml files.In .xaml files i can link the DB tables,So it connects there and retrieves automatically what ever datats are there.So top command is not useful

Comment: @AmitSingh i think there are some bugs in your code because when i run using yours then visual studio hangs and restarts automatically

Comment: @javaBeginner it doesnt have bug....that is the way to update using join in sql server  2008....

Comment: @AmitSingh I am helpless why it restarts,can not find an answer

Comment: @javaBeginner its very strange for me too.,,,try to run on sql server management studio